# Default destructor nothrow

Tags: c++, c++11

The following code doesn't compile under gcc-4.7.1 but compile under clang-3.2.  Which one follows the C++11 standard?

```
struct X {
  virtual ~X() = default;
};

struct Y : X {
  virtual ~Y() = default;
};
```

gcc-4.7.1 complains that:

```
looser throw specifier for 'virtual Y::~Y()'
error: overriding 'virtual X::~X() noexcept(true)'
```

Obviously, gcc-4.7.1 thinks X's default destructor nothrow, but Y's default destructor is not nothrow.  Why is this?  Can anyone refer to the correct place in standard?  Thanks.

I saw similar questions on stackoverflow, but I didn't see the answers refering to the standard.

Comment: Most probably a bug in the compiler if your code is exactly like the one in the question.

Comment: FYI g++ snapshot 20120708 compiles the code properly.

Comment: great question, bumped exactly into this today when trying to port something on Debian g++4.7

Answer (score 39, accepted):

**The compilers are caught in a dilemma here**, for the following reasons:

(1) **Not specifying any exceptions** in a function declaration (i.e. not using `throw` nor `noexcept` (which is equivalent to `noexcept(true)` )) means to allow that function to throw **all possible exceptions**:

> (§15.4/12, emphasis mine) A function with **no exception-speciﬁcation** or with an exception-speciﬁcation of the form `noexcept(constant-expression)` where the `constant-expression` yields `false` **allows all exceptions.** [...]

(2) A **default destructor** must allow exactly the exceptions that are allowed by the functions directly invoked by its implicit definition:

> (§15.4/14, emphasis mine) An implicitly declared special member function (Clause 12) shall have an exception-speciﬁcation. **If f is an implicitly declared** default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, **destructor**, copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, **its implicit exception-speciﬁcation speciﬁes the type-id T if and only if T is allowed by the exception-speciﬁcation of a function directly invoked by f’s implicit deﬁnition**; f shall allow all exceptions if any function it directly invokes allows all exceptions, and f shall allow no exceptions if every function it directly invokes allows no exceptions.

(3) When a special member (such as a destructor) is *explicitly defaulted*, i.e. when you use `= default`, the exception specification is **optional** (see the use of "*may* have" below):

> (8.4.2/2, emphasis mine) An **explicitly-defaulted function** [...] **may have** an explicit exception-speciﬁcation only if it is compatible (15.4) with the exception-speciﬁcation on the implicit declaration. [...]

There is no statement in the Standard that requires the exception specification in an explicitly defaulted destructor.

**Conclusion:** Therefore, **not specifiying the exceptions** of an explicitly defaulted destructor can be interpreted in two ways:

- To mean that *all exceptions are allowed* (according to (1) above)
- Or, alternatively, to mean that *exactly the same exceptions are allowed as are allowed by the implicit default definition of the destructor* (according to (3) above), which in your case means to allow *no exceptions* (according to (2) above).

Unfortunately, GCC resolves this dilemma in one way (in favor of "no exceptions") in the case of your base class declaration, and in a different way in the case of the derived class (in favor of "all exceptions" there).

**I believe the most natural interpretation of this admittedly ambiguous situation is to assume that (2) and (3) override (1).** The Standard does not say so, but it should. Under that interpretation, Clang seems to be right here.

Comment: Nice answer, the problem is actually quite important, as you may declare (as I did) a singleton with a `=default` protected destructor using the CRTP pattern, and then all g++ compilers <= 4.7 will spit out the same error about "looser throw..." However for g++ >= 4.8, the code compiles just fine. My solution to portable code is to just write the destructor as `virtual ~Destructor(){};`. Not elegant, but works on g++ 4.7 and higher versions.