# How to declare the virtual destructor without breaking move and copy constructors

Tags: c++, c++11, virtual-destructor

When adding a user defined default virtual destructor to a class like this..

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo();
    virtual ~Foo() = default;
};
```

.. It has the side effects of preventing auto generation of move constructors. Also auto generation of copy constructors is deprecated. [A recommended way is to user define all constructors](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29289980/212010) like this..

```
class Foo
{
public:
  Foo();
  virtual ~Foo() = default;
  Foo(const Foo& /* other */) = default;
  Foo&operator=(const Foo& /* other */) = default;
  Foo(Foo&& /* other */) = default;
  Foo&operator=(Foo&& /* other */) = default;
};
```

However, this is super verbose and unreadable. Are there any other solutions to this?

Comment: If you have a virtual dtor, you probably want to **delete** all copy and move ctors anyway.

Comment: And potentially have a `clone()` method instead.

Comment: I would argue that you want those last four lines in all classes *anyway* (possibly with `= delete` rather than `= default`) - just to be clear about what the class is providing.  (Arguably if you delete the "copy" functions, you don't need to mention the "move" functions.)

Comment: @MartinBonner I think all the last _five_ last lines should be avoided _if at all possible_. By raii design that is almost alway possible. Duplicating five lines of boilerplate all over the place do not add to clarity. But if you add one, then add the rest!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First I would consider whether `Foo` really needs a virtual destructor. Maybe you can solve your problem in a type safe manner using a simple template, saving you from messing with pointers and casting and so on.

If you decide on making `Foo` virtual, then I would recommend this abstraction.

```
class VirtualDestructor
{
protected:
  VirtualDestructor() = default;
  virtual ~VirtualDestructor() = default;
  VirtualDestructor(const VirtualDestructor & /* other */) = default;
  VirtualDestructor &operator=(const VirtualDestructor & /* other */) = default;
  VirtualDestructor(VirtualDestructor && /* other */) = default;
  VirtualDestructor &operator=(VirtualDestructor && /* other */) = default;
};
```

Put this in a library in an appropriate `namespace`. Then you can keep `Foo` and all other virtual classes clean.

```
class Foo : VirtualDestructor
{
public:
    Foo();
};
```

The same technique can also be used when deleting for example copy constructors.

**Edit:**
[Compiler output](https://godbolt.org/g/AS5SS4) and [diff with original code](https://www.diffchecker.com/IJPPls8W)

Comment: Can you elaborate on the difference, if any, in the behavior of `Foo` when having these `= default` definitions directly in it, and its behavior when it inherits them from `VirtualDestructor`?

Comment: @einpoklum Updated answer with compiler output of the two versions.

Comment: virtual destructor does not suppress `operator=` so I would suggest removing those from your class  (your choices impose a condition on derived classes, they might have wanted to use copy-and-swap for example)