# C++ Why adding a destructor to my class makes my class unmovable?

Tags: c++, grammar, move-semantics

The compiler reminds me that I'm using a deleted function .
https://ideone.com/3YAIlA

```
#include <memory>
using namespace std;
class foo
{
public:
    unique_ptr<int> p;
    ~foo()
    {

    }
};
int main()
{
    foo a, b;
    a = move(b);
    return 0;
}
```

compilation info

```
prog.cpp: In function 'int main()':
prog.cpp:15:4: error: use of deleted function 'foo& foo::operator=(const foo&)'
  a = move(b);


prog.cpp:3:7: note: 'foo& foo::operator=(const foo&)' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class foo


prog.cpp:3:7: error: use of deleted function 'std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>& std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::operator=(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = int; _Dp = std::default_delete<int>]'

In file included from /usr/include/c++/5/memory:81:0,
                 from prog.cpp:1:


/usr/include/c++/5/bits/unique_ptr.h:357:19: note: declared here
       unique_ptr& operator=(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
```

If I remove the destructor ,my code compiles fine.
https://ideone.com/UFB18P

Comment: I understand that it cannot be copied, but the move constructor? Hmmm

Comment: The chart in this answer is a good summary of the rules for when and what the compiler does for you regarding special members: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38687106/576911

Comment: If you *really*  need a destructor for the class, it is very unlikely that the default move operations will do the right thing. Like if you have a raw pointer and need to delete it in the destructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because [that's what the standard says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4820339/560648). When you start adding special member functions, you inhibit the automatic generation of some of the other ones. This is in the same category of rules as how writing a non-default constructor means a default one won't be automatically generated for you.

Add this:

```
foo& operator=(foo&&) = default;
```