# Compiler warning when a class breaks rule-of-three (five)

Tags: c++, c++11, gcc, compiler-flags

Is it possible to trigger compiler warning when a class breaks rule-of-three (or rule-of-five)?

This feature sounds easy to implement and is very useful in safety critical software but I can't find it anywhere in documentation or Google search results.

Comment: This might be idealist claptrap but IMHO it's far better to build your classes in such a way that you never need to implement the functions required for the rule-of-three or the rule-of-five.

Comment: @Bathsheba absolutely agree. If you're not using rule of zero then your code is not sufficiently decomposed.

Comment: I personally would not like to have a check for Rule of five as I'm not sure it's a good guideline. Please check this discussion by Howard Hinnant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/38687106/1989995

Comment: Rule of zero is great but only works because people are following rule of five elsewhere. Someone has gotta implement the special member functions eventually.

Comment: GCC tracks this under <https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=88050>.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the compiler flag [-Weffc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.8.1/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html) for GCC

Comment: -Weffc++ does find some interesting issues, but it doesn't find "rule of five" violations. I'm using current gcc from the gcc-8-branch. Neither does current clang.

Comment: seconded. `-Weffc++` does not catch this

Comment: [example of clean compilation with that flag](https://wandbox.org/permlink/JTOCTyhNlapSnjzt)

Comment: How does a blatantly false answer like this get 7 upvotes?

Answer (score 3):

[`clang-tidy`](http://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/) can catch such mistakes. Given this file:

```
// badstyle.cpp
class Type {
  Type(const Type&) { }

  ~Type() { }
};
```

And this command:

```
$ clang-tidy badstyle.cpp -checks=cppcoreguidelines-*
```

My output is:

```
badstyle.cpp:2:7: warning: class 'Type' defines a non-default destructor and a 
copy constructor but does not define a copy assignment operator, a move constructor
or a move assignment operator [cppcoreguidelines-special-member-functions]
class Type {
  ^
```

Answer (score 2):

Visual Studio 2017 RC [states](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes) to have some "Checkers for enforcing the C++ Core Guidelines". Since the "Rule of five" is one of the most easily checked rules, I believe it's implemented.