# What is the difference: Derived class constructor with initializing by calling abstract class constructor using dereferencing or not?

Tags: c++, constructor

I have an abstract (template) class `tXmlNode` from which I have derived the template class `tXmlGeometry`. This derived class shall be constructed with a pointer to an object of varying type hence it is created as a template. This object shall be transferred to the derived class via a pointer.

My current implementation of the constructor of the derived class is as follows (I leave out the scope implementation as it is not relevant to my question I think):

```
nXml::tXmlGeometry<Part>::tXmlGeometry(Part* part) : tXmlNode<Part>(part)
```

My compiler (MS VisualStudio 2019) accepts this. But it also accepts that:

```
nXml::tXmlGeometry<Part>::tXmlGeometry(Part* part) : tXmlNode<Part>(*part)
```

What is the exact difference here? As far as I understand it the second one calls the constructor of the abstract class and transfers the content of `part` to this `tXmlNode` constructor whereas the first one does what?

Now I am currently creating an abstract class `tXmlSegment` that inherits from `tXmlGeometry`.

The constructor for this new abstract class is formulated as follows:

```
nXml::tXmlSegment2D::tXmlSegment2D(tXmlGeometry<Part>* geo, const int npos) : tXmlGeometry<Part>(*geo), position(npos)
```

What is curious is that my compiler now insists of getting the dereferenced `geo` object and I don't understand the reason for that. Why is it so that I have to dereference it?

EDIT:
The constructor of tXmlNode is as follows:

```
template<class Node>
    inline tXmlNode<Node>::tXmlNode(
        Node* node,
        const int npos) : xml_doc(nullptr), node(node), n_childs(0), n_attr(0), position(npos)
```

Comment: And what are constructor signatures for `tXmlNode<Part>()`?

Comment: `tXmlGeometry<Part>(*geo)` is using the copy constructor of your base

Comment: @alagner: I've edited the post accordingly.

Comment: @Caleth: I am not sure if I implemented one. I've added the signature of the constructor of the base class. To my understanding it should call this one.

Comment: You either declare a copy constructor yourself, or the compiler implicitly generates one.

Comment: @ManyQuestions try explicitly marking your copyconstructor as `delete`, you'll see ;)
https://stackoverflow.com/a/38687106/4885321 edit: chart at the bottom of the post is what I'm explicitly pointing at.

Comment: Oh sh*t, I have never dealt with such constructors. :D I am learning C++ while writing...

Comment: @alagar: thanks for the link which is very instructive. However, I am still not sure why in one case it accepts both ```*part``` and ```part``` whereas in the other it only takes ````*part```. These classes are pretty similar, none have a user move or copy constructor as far as I understand this (and I don't understand much :D)