# Difference between explicit default destructor and none

Tags: c++11

What is the difference between explicitly declaring a default destructor (using `= default`), and not declaring anything ? Are there cases when it is required to explicitely define at least a default destructor ?

Please note that I am not speaking about needing to free some allocated memory, I'm asking about destructors that do nothing but the default

I could not came across a case where the former has a different behaviour than the latter. In both cases the compiler seems to generate a call to parents destructor or members destructors.

In those two cases, both behaviours (with or without explicitly defaulted destructor) seem equivalent :

```
// 1
struct A {
    ~A() { std::cout << "~A()\n"; }
};

struct B : public A {
    // Comment this line out
    ~B() = default; 
};

// 2
struct C { 
    ~C() { std::cout << "~C()\n"; }
};

struct D {
    // Comment this line out
    ~D() = default;
    C c;
};

int main() {
    B b;
    D d;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29289980/3932569) to a different question can give you some useful information

Comment: Indeed the answer and the slides kinda answer my question, thanks :)

Comment: @Zouch So... is it fine to mark this one as a dupe?

Comment: Well if it is the only answer I guess it's fine yeah